# How to show and hide Dropdown Menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've question on Dropdown Menu using jQuery and CSS, below is my HTML structure:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Icons.png" alt="a"/>
            <div class="menu" id="a">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Icons.png" alt="b"/>
            <div class="menu" id="b">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Icons.png" alt="c"/>
            <div class="menu" id="c">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I wanted to achieve when mouse over to image, the div will display and show the menu, the menu link is clickable, while when mouse away from the image, the div will be hidden or user mouse away the menu.

Please advise, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Man i really recommend you use unordered lists instead of tables, 
Your html will look something like this:

```
<nav id="main-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="whatever.jpg" alt="" />
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And your styles:

```
#main-nav > ul {}
#main-nav > ul > li {}
#main-nav > ul > li > a {}
#main-nav > ul > li:hover > ul { display:block; }
#main-nav > ul > li > ul { display:none; }
#main-nav > ul > li > ul > li {}
#main-nav > ul > li > ul > li > a {}
```

You can use this html/css to make what you want to work

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by adding two CSS classes as follows:

```
.hidden
{
display: none;
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
}

.show
{
/*add any styling desired when showing*/
}
```

Then for the mouse over effect:

```
window.onload = function(){
     document.getElementById('imageId').onmouseover = function() {
          document.getElementById('menuId').classname = 'show';
     }

     document.getElementById('imageId').onmouseout = function() {
          document.getElementById('menuId').classname = 'hidden';
     }
}
```

Then just set the default css class for your menus to the hidden class and you should be fine.

Comment: thanks for your replied, the problem is the menu will be gone once mouse out the image